# ¿Como sumar tiempos en SQL en función de una condición?

Tags: sql, postgresql, algoritmos

Utiliso PostGreSQL y quiero hacer un algoritmo con SQL que me permite saber cuentos tiempos un utilisado "swipe", es por decir pasa cosas a la manera de tinder.
Un utilisador "swipe" cuando `swipe.state= 3,6,9`.

Sin embargo solo tengo la fecha de los swipe. Entonces pienso que puedo saberlo un algoritmo por cada usario:

```
WHILE fecha_i + tiempo_i + epsilon >= fecha_j + tiempo_j + epsilon
    tiempo_pasado = tiempo_pasado + tiempo_i
END WHILE
```

Como puedo traducirlo en SQL con la base de datos mostrada ?

He intentado sumar el tiempo pasado por el suscriber 160 pero no existe `tiempo_i`:

```
SELECT SUM(tiempo_i) AS tiempo_pasado
    FROM swipe
    WHERE swipe.date + tiempo_i + 10000 >= swipe.date + tiempo_i
    AND sucriber_id = 160;
```

Yo sé que podemos utilisar lo siguiente para anadir tiempos en dias:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day','m/j/a h:m:s'::timestamp + 'm/j/a h:m:s'::timestamp)
```

**Quiero hacer esto para conocer la media del tiempo pasado por los utilisadores con los swipe.**

Aqui esta la tabla `swipe`:
[image: base de datos swipe]

#### Actualización

Aqui esta lo que he intentado para obtener los tiempos de sesión. Pero necesito calcular la medi y no sé como agregar los que he definido como una sesión para calcular la media.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE calculTemps(IN tiempo_session INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT swipe.date FROM swipe
        -- queremos las fechas de los momentos cuando el usuario esta utilisando la app
        -- es por decir el tiempo entre dos swipe esta menos que el tiempo_session
        WHERE (swipe.date - swipe.date.2 <= tiempo_session)
              AND (swipe.state=2 OR swipe.state=3 OR swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state = 6 OR swipe.state=8 OR swipe.state = 9)

        -- queremos hacer aqui la media del tiempo de session
END|
```

Comment: podrias decirnos que motor de base de datos ocupas

Comment: quieres sumar el campo date con el campo time_on cuando el state sea (3,6,9)?

Comment: @JackNavaRow cuando el state sea 3,6,9

Answer (score 0):

Como no me quedó del todo claro las condiciones de contorno van varias soluciones

## sql puro

Sirve para sumar el tiempo en base a una condición para cualquier motor SQL y funciona cuando solo quieres ese dato

```
SELECT SUM(tiempo_i) AS tiempo_pasado
  FROM la_tabla_o_vista
  WHERE fecha_i + tiempo_i + epsilon >= fecha_j + tiempo_j + epsilon
```

## sum(case)

No todos los motores podrían aceptarlo. **Ventaja** se pueden calcular otras cosas al mismo tiempo:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN fecha_i + tiempo_i + epsilon >= fecha_j + tiempo_j + epsilon THEN tiempo_i 
        ELSE NULL 
    END) AS tiempo_pasado,
    SUM(otro_campo) AS otra_suma
  FROM la_tabla_o_vista
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero tiempo_i esta una variable significando el tiempo pasado por el usario en la app, es por decir no esta en la base de datos. Lo cronstruyo cuando la condición esta espectada. Pienso que debo inciarla pero no sé como hacerlo en SQL.

Comment: haz un procedimiento almacenado y pasas por parametro esa variable

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias. He descuvierto y constructado una primera parte en la Actualización